# Changing color for each element in linerenderer not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change color for each line(element) just like in color switch. But my code is not working. Whats wrong with my code?

```
void Start()
{
    lineGeneratorPrefab = new GameObject();
    DrawLine();
}


private void DrawLine()
{
    GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
    myLine.transform.position = start;
    myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    lr.positionCount = 4;

    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(-2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(2, -2, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(-2, -2, 0));
    lr.materials[2].color = Color.blue;
    lr.materials[3].color = Color.red;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of your current code vs what you want? As an aside, 'AddComponent' returns the component that was just added.

Comment: @Reasurria the result code returns all line in color blue. What I wanted is that the right line should turn blue then the down line should turn color red. "AddComponent' returns the component that was just added" what do you mean sir? Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Take at look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-colorGradient.html).

Instead of altering the various materials, you could instead change the gradient of the line renderer through the `colorGradient` property.

So in your case you could add the following:

```
 gradient.SetKeys(
    new GradientColorKey[] { 
            new GradientColorKey(Color.red,0.0f), 
            new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 0.25f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.blue, 0.5f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.blue, 1.0f)},
            // Alpha key
        );
```

If you want a more abrupt transition, you could add color keys at 0.49 and 0.51 for example.

Comment: will try this one. Thanks

Comment: doesn't give me what I wanted. I'll study this further. thanks for heads up

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and unexpected color blending happens whether or not you have your gradient keys set tight unless your LineRenderer is really high resolution. My use case requires no blending at all (just sudden changes between colors). I solved it by creating a shader that changes the vertex colors based on a vertex color map/texture set at runtime.

For this to work, the LineRenderer needs to have at least 1 set in the Corner Vertices property. You also need have positions set where your color changes occur, but I made it easy to use with the following shader, class, and struct.

Here is the shader (it is unlit and for URP):

```
Shader "Unlit/LineRenderer"
{
    Properties {
        [Header(Surface options)]

        [MainColor] _ColorTint("Tint", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _VertexColorMap("Vertex Color Map", 2D) = "white"
    }
    SubShader{

        Tags {"RenderType" = "Opaque" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline"}
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            Name "ForwardLit"
            Tags{"LightMode" = "UniversalForward"}

            HLSLPROGRAM 

            #pragma vertex Vertex
            #pragma fragment Fragment

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

            struct Attributes {
                float4 positionOS   : POSITION;
                uint vertexID : SV_VertexID;
            };

            struct Interpolators {
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float4 positionHCS  : SV_POSITION;
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_VertexColorMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_VertexColorMap);

            CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
                float4 _VertexColorMap_ST;
                float4 _ColorTint;
                float4 _VertexColorMap_TexelSize;
            CBUFFER_END

            Interpolators Vertex(Attributes input) {
                Interpolators output;

                float2 uv = float2((input.vertexID == 0) ? _VertexColorMap_TexelSize.x : input.vertexID * _VertexColorMap_TexelSize.x, 0.5);
                output.color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_LOD(_VertexColorMap, sampler_VertexColorMap, uv.xy, 0.0, 0.0);
                output.positionHCS = TransformObjectToHClip(input.positionOS.xyz);

                return output;
            }

            float4 Fragment(Interpolators input) : SV_TARGET {
                return input.color * _ColorTint;
            }

            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

Just put that shader on a material and set the line renderer to use that material. Then you will need to also need this static LineRendererExtension class and LineRendererPositionParams struct:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public struct LineRendererPositionParams
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; }
    public Color32 InColor { get; }
    public Color32 OutColor { get; }

    public LineRendererPositionParams(
        Vector3 position,
        Color32 inColor,
        Color32 outColor)
    {
        Position = position;
        InColor = inColor;
        OutColor = outColor;
    }
}


public static class LineRendererExtensions
{
    public static List<Color32> SetPositionsWithColors(this LineRenderer @this, List<LineRendererPositionParams> positionParams)
    {
        @this.positionCount = positionParams.Count;
        @this.SetPositions(positionParams.Select(p => p.Position).ToArray());

        var colors = @this.GetEndCapColors(positionParams[0].InColor);

        for (var i = 1; i < positionParams.Count-1; i++)
            colors.AddRange(@this.GetSegmentConnectionColors(positionParams[i]));

        colors.AddRange(@this.GetEndCapColors(positionParams[positionParams.Count-1].InColor));

        return colors;
    }

    public static void SetVertexColorMap(this LineRenderer @this, Color32[] colors, Texture2D texture)
    {
        if (texture.width != colors.Length)
            texture.Reinitialize(colors.Length, 1);

        texture.SetPixels32(colors.ToArray());
        texture.Apply();
        @this.material.SetTexture("_VertexColorMap", texture);
    }

    private static List<Color32> GetSegmentConnectionColors(this LineRenderer @this, LineRendererPositionParams positionParams)
    {
        Debug.Assert(@this.numCornerVertices > 1,
            $"The number of corner vertices of a {nameof(LineRenderer)} cannot be less than 1 when using {nameof(LineRendererPositionParams)}");

        var colors = new List<Color32>();
        var half = (@this.numCornerVertices/2) * 2 + 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < half; i++)
            colors.Add(positionParams.InColor);

        if (@this.numCornerVertices%2 != 0)
            colors.AddRange(@this.GetMidPointColors(positionParams));

        for (var i = 0; i < half; i++)
            colors.Add(positionParams.OutColor);

        return colors;
    }

    private static List<Color32> GetMidPointColors(this LineRenderer @this, LineRendererPositionParams positionParams)
    {
        var color = Color32.Lerp(positionParams.InColor, positionParams.OutColor, 0.5f);
        return new List<Color32>() {color, color};
    }

    private static List<Color32> GetEndCapColors(this LineRenderer @this, Color32 color)
    {
        if (@this.numCapVertices == 0)
            return new List<Color32>() {color, color};

        var colors = new List<Color32>() {color, color, color, color, color, color};
        var remaining = (@this.numCapVertices - 1) * 2 + 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < remaining; i++)
            colors.Add(color);

        return colors;
    }
}
```

So you just need to create a list of LineRendererPositionParams which have all the positions and colors of your LineRenderer and then just use the extension `lineRenderer.SetPositionsWithColors(positionParams);` which returns a list of colors which you use on the other extension `lineRenderer.SetVertexColorMap(lineRenderer.SetPositionsWithColors(positionParams), texture);` and it should work as expected. The texture you pass in only gets reinitialized if the texture/line vertex size changes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer KTobiasson!
I did port your shader to work with the built-in render pipeline.
The code is only slightly modified as I required the line to be transparent and be correctly rendered in VR.

```
Shader "Unlit/CustomLineRenderer"
{
    Properties
    {
        [MainColor] _ColorTint("Tint", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _VertexColorMap("Vertex Color Map", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100
        
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
    
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                uint vertexID : SV_VertexID;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct Interpolators {
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float4 vertex  : SV_POSITION;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };
            
            sampler2D _VertexColorMap;

            CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
                float4 _VertexColorMap_ST;
                float4 _ColorTint;
                float4 _VertexColorMap_TexelSize;
            CBUFFER_END
            
            Interpolators vert (appdata v)
            {
                Interpolators o;

                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
                
                float2 uv = float2((v.vertexID == 0) ? _VertexColorMap_TexelSize.x : v.vertexID * _VertexColorMap_TexelSize.x, 0.5);
                o.color = tex2Dlod(_VertexColorMap, float4(uv.xy, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex.xyz);
                
                return o;
            }
            
            fixed4 frag (Interpolators i) : SV_Target
            {
                return i.color * _ColorTint;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```